# Flask server won't stop on Ctrl+C in Windows

Tags: python, flask

I created a default basic web server with Flask from Visual Studio templates.
When I launch it from the command prompt it says "Press Ctrl+C to quit". When I do press Ctrl+C, nothing happens and the server keeps running.

Question: Is there a way to make Flask stop on Ctrl+C as advertised?

This is the code of server startup:

```
from os import environ
from myapp import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

Comment: Do you get any response when CTRL^C?

Comment: It keeps running even in Linux... Mark to look for answer.

Comment: try CTRL+Break instead

Comment: @Vinny, no response at all, it just keeps running. One thing I noticed - if no pages have been served, then Ctrl+C works fine. If at least one request has been processed, then Ctrl+C has no effect.

Comment: @IrmendeJong - Ctrl+Break worked!! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: CTRL+Break terminates an SSH session.

Comment: Don't use CTRL+Break

Answer (score 6):

To stop a Flask server running on Windows:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
2. If Flask is still running, try: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>
3. If Flask is *still* running, open a command terminal or PowerShell and run:

```
taskkill /f /im python.exe
```

You can also select a specific Python process to kill:

```
> tasklist /fi "imagename eq python.exe"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
python.exe                    1080 Console                    8     72,456 K
python.exe                   15860 Console                    8     73,344 K

> taskkill /F /pid 15860
SUCCESS: The process with PID 15860 has been terminated.
```

4. If the server is only run on the local computer, another option is to [create an endpoint to kill the server](http://web.archive.org/web/20190706125149/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67).

```
from flask import request
def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

@app.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

Answer (score 2):

### I'm surprised no one has mentioned this command

###### Although this is not perfect, see below text.

```
sudo pkill -f "flask"
```

of course this will have some cons, since it's a kill command. If you have multiple flask instances running, it will kill ALL of them, just as most of the other kill commands. To get around this, you can make a **route** that is used to programically shutdown the flask server.

## Example:

```
@app.route('/shutdown')
def shutdown():
    sys.exit()
    os.exit(0)
    return
```

What his does; is, it will exit the program whenever **/shutdown** is triggered.
Of course this will need security, so no-random can spam shutdown your server.

Lets say you have a session called `session['logged_in']`
you would want to check if this session is **True** before shutting down the server.

**Below should be working:**

```
@app.route('/shutdown')
def shutdown():

    # If not logged in, return back to the login page.
    if not session or not session['logged_in']:
        return render_template('loginpage.html')

    # Logged_in, continue...
    sys.exit()
    os.exit(0)
    return
```

Hopefully this helped

Comment: That would work, but OP has asked for a solution on Windows

Comment: I mean, the code should be working on any platform 

Answer (score 0):

You should use TASKKILL in a new command prompt window

Answer (score -1):

although it's a strange problem you can kill the flask by run this command in linux command line:

```
sudo kill servicename
```

replace servicename with service PID

you can get it by run this command:

```
sudo ps -A | grep "python(x)"
```

where x  it's python version

Comment: Thanks, but this is for Linux, I'm running it on Windows

Comment: in windows you can use tasklist command to list the running service on machine and taskkill to stop it. read this article for more details